# Blink in returning Material Shared Element Transition when using elevation in Card (Android)

Tags: android, android-animation, material-components-android, shared-element-transition, materialcardview

I followed the documentation for implementing Container Transform Transitions between 2 different activities (https://m3.material.io/libraries/mdc-android/motion#container-transform).

---

The problem is when I am using elevation in my Card in let's say **Activity A** (*MainActivity* in my case), then just after returning back from **Activity B** (*Wallpaper* in my case) doing the same transition backwards, the specific **card's shadow blinks**.

***It's only noticeable when I am using the elevation.***

---

Related Code: https://github.com/Sujal1245/WALLisWALL-Wallpaper-App

Example: https://youtu.be/fiMzAIcP23o

Comment: It would be better if you shared a demo code. No one can provide time to recreate the code

Comment: @RaghavSatyadev Thank you. I have added the related repo.